# Excel (.xlsx) - Drop-down lists/tables - Include specific values/text in drop-down list selection

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, selection, data-validation

Say I have a column, "Names", of single and multiple names (where two can occupy once cell), e.g.

**Names**

`Anna`

`Bruce`

`Charlie`

`Bruce / Charlie`

`Anna / Bruce`

Upon creating a table I am given a drop-down list of each individual option, but selecting only "`Anna`", for instance, won't also bring up "`Anna / Bruce`".

I am unfamiliar with Excel, but my question is:

How do I do it so that when I select "`Anna`", all cells that have "`Anna`" in them, e.g. including "`Anna / Bruce`", will also appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to use a `Text Filter` that `Contains` "Anna".

[image]

You can type "Anna" in the `Contains` field to show only cells that have "Anna" somewhere in the cell.

[image]

This will return cells like "Anna/Bruce", "Andrew/Anna", ect.

[image]

The selections that are available with check boxes are limited to the unique cells found in the column. Custom choices cannot be added here, relaying us to use a `Text Filter` instead.

Comment: Is there a way so that selecting "Anna" in the main drop down will have a similar (and thus expedient) result?

Comment: The selections with the check boxes represent each unique cell in the column. You cannot add a custom "where-cell-contains-Anna" selection with a check box to this list.

Comment: @AndrewCina, To answer your comment, the check boxes should not be used in case you desire to use the *Contains* functionality - which is what you are looking for